# tensorflow tokenizer No such file or directoy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have converted Dataframe columns texts to

```
ShuffleDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.int64)
```

when i tokenize it give following error

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

vocabulary_set = set()
for text_tensor ,_ in all_labeled_data:
  some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(all_labeled_data.numpy())
  vocabulary_set.update(some_tokens)

vocab_size = len(vocabulary_set)
vocab_size
```

The Error is Showing text which was going to be tokenize are marked as file directory by tokenizer

```
     66    Waits for ops dispatched in this executor to > finish.
---> 67     > pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
     68 
     69   def clear_error(self):

NotFoundError: RE: VyprVPN for Business; No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running this locally? Or in something like Google Colab?

Comment: i am running in Colab